# Create a Tensor from std::vector<Tensor> values

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm doing a DQN training with dynamic batch size. I have two pass:

First pass:
Several subsequent forward propagations of the DNN with different samples until some specific event occurs. During this step I save all inputs (which are one-dimensional Tensors) for replay in the second pass. Because with C++ I cannot create a Tensor with a dynamic shape, I store them as a std::vector of the one-dimensional tensors.

Second pass:
Compute the expected output and use the same DNN to perform forward propagation plus back propagation. This time I use two-dimensional tensor as input, to compute all samples in one run.

The question is how do I most efficiently create this two-dimensional input Tensor from the vector of one-dimensional Tensors? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a tensor from a vector of vectors! define a vector and each element of that vector is also a vector. 
for example:

```
 vector<int> tensor(i,vector<int> (j)); //the size is i*j where i and j are integers
```

for accessing the element of ij you can access it in this way:

```
tensor[i][j]
```

The size of this tensor is dynamic since the size of a vector is dynamic